# Efficiently copy images in onenote

Tags: c#, office-interop, onenote

I'm currently working on a project that requires OneNote automation. Now I need to copy images from a page to another. I've found out some APIs on the Microsoft site like GetPageContent, UpdatePageContent to do this. Currently I am manually copy the one:Image Data into the new page. It works but to retrieve all the binary images takes quite a time. Is there any easier approach to achieve this? I've tried to use the Callback ID but it seems that a copied image gives a different ID so I can't just copy that.

I'm using Onenote 2013.

Regards,

ShiroYacha

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to refer to the image that exists on another page when inserting an image to a page. What you are doing by copying the `one:Image` data is the only available approach for this.